# Test linearity versus local linearity in regression

Tags: regression, nonparametric

I have a question regarding local linear least squares vs OLS.

Consider the linear regression model

$$y_{i}=x_{i}'\beta+\epsilon_{it}$$

where we have assumed that the model is linear in its parameters. Under suitable exogeneity assumptions, we can write the conditional mean as

$$E[y_{i}|x_{i}]=x_{i}\beta.$$

We can estimate the parameter vector $\beta$ consistently using OLS.
If we do not wish to impose linearity, we can estimate the model non parameterically, for instance, by local linear least squares.

The local linear leasts squares estimate of the parameter vector is given by

$$\hat{\beta}(x)=\mbox{argmin }(y_{i}-(x-x_{i})'\beta)^{2}F_{K}(x-x_{i}).$$

I understand that standard errors are higher for non parametric estimators such as this one. Assuming linearity definitely buys us precision, but it is restrictive.

Now, given that $\hat{\beta}(x)$ is a parameter vector that depends on $x$, can we construct some sort of distance type test (Like the Hausmann test for instance), where we compute

$$D=(\hat{\beta}(x)-\beta_{OLS})'W(\hat{\beta}(x)-\hat{\beta}_{OLS})$$

and compare how good our linearity assumption is?

The space of X's over which we would test could be the X's that are present in the data..

Comment: Linearity does not rest on an assumption of joint normality.

Comment: I took that part out..it is still restrictive though

Comment: Actually, I just checked online, linearity is only true in very special cases, one of which is when X and Y are jointly normal..

Comment: hejseb is still right. Linearity and normality are independent assumptions; you can have either one, both or none.

Comment: ?? Joint normality of X and Y does imply that the CEF is linear..How are they independent assumptions?Of course, X and Y could be independent, in which case the CEF is a constant function..

Comment: Off the top of my head, you could add non-linear transformations of your data and see if the coefficients are jointly distinguishable from zero.

Eg. If your regression was $y_i = a + b \cdot x_i + e_i$, run regression $y_i = a + b_1 \cdot x_i + b_2 \cdot x_i^2 + e_i$ and test if $b_2$ is zero. More generally (with $x_i^3$, $x_jx_i$ terms etc...), this would be testing a linear restriction on your coefficients via an F test.

Comment: Yes but it would still be a linear regression..

Comment: What is CEF?...

Comment: Conditional Expectation Function

Comment: @ChinG, probably you have in mind some subject-matter argument, because there is no statistical argument to associate linearity and normality the way you suggest.

Comment: As far as I know, if X and Y are jointly normally distributed, then the conditional mean of Y is linear in X